# Tweepy throwing traceback errors?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, traceback

So I am relatively new to Python and don't know a ton about programming in general. I've been trying to just write a stupid meme twitter bot that me and my friends thought of as a joke. But I just wanted to see if I could get it running. And of course I can't. And I'm having trouble understanding how to handle a traceback error based on documentation and forum posts alone.

I am running python 3.7 in Pycharm on Windows, if any of this makes any difference. Will update with details as asked/needed.

Up until this point I've tried:
-Removing other Java interpreter versions.
-Uninstalling and reinstalling tweepy using pip.
-Maybe some other stuff can't quite remember but these being the main things I tried.

Code shown here:

```
import random
import tweepy


consumer_key = 'Insert Consumer Key'
consumer_secret = 'Insert Consumer Secret'
access_token = 'Access Token Goes Here'
access_token_secret = 'access token secret goes here'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

chance = random.randint(1, 1001)


def powder(num=chance / 100):
    if num == 0.01:
    api.update_status("*Special 0.01% chance tweet* I have a better monitor so I should be better at tekken.")
    print("*Special 0.01% chance tweet* I have a better monitor so I should be better at tekken.")
elif num <= 27.3:
    api.update_status("Hmmm. That's a lot of powder.")
    print("Hmmm. That's a lot of powder.")
else:
    api.update_status("Yes.")
    print("Yes.")


 powder()
```

And the error thrown looks like this:

```
C:\Users\colem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe 
C:/Users/colem/PycharmProjects/Playground/powder.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/colem/PycharmProjects/Playground/powder.py", line 29, in <module>
powder()
  File "C:/Users/colem/PycharmProjects/Playground/powder.py", line 22, in powder
api.update_status("Hmmm. That's a lot of powder.")
  File "C:\Users\colem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 194, in update_status
)(post_data=post_data, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\colem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 250, in _call
return method.execute()
  File "C:\Users\colem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 234, in execute
raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 32, 'message': 'Could not authenticate you.'}]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Sorry if this formatting is terrible, my first Stack Overflow post.

Comment: Do you *have* an access token and all that other stuff, or did you literally write `'Access Token Goes Here'`?

Comment: No it's censorship. Lol